excel.pdb not loaded in VS2022 when debugging attached excel process
I am trying to debug my dll (IFORT) in Visual Studio 2022 ver. 17.11.1, to which I attach an excel process. However, excel.pdb is not found on Microsoft-Symbol Server. How can I retrieve the missing pdb-file?
I have added the path to the symbol server and expected the excel.pdb to be retrieved but I get in the symbol--loading-info "https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols: Skipped checking location. The symbol file was not previously found at this location."
